# Cannot use X as Y because the name is already in use, even though it's not

Tags: php

I'm using PHP 5.4, and have a PSR-0 class structure similar to the following.

**A\Library\Session.php**:

```php
namespace A\Library;

class Session { ... }
```

**My\Application\Session.php**:

```php
namespace My\Application;

class Session { ... }
```

**My\Application\Facebook.php**:

```php
namespace My\Application;
use A\Library\Session;

class Facebook { ... }
```

When I try to run the application, I get the following error:

> Cannot use A\Library\Session as Session because the name is already in use in My\Application\Facebook.php

Even though it's not, at least not in this file. The Facebook.php file declares only the `Facebook` class, and imports exactly one `Session` class, the `A\Library` one.

The only problem I can see is that another `Session` class exists in the same namespace as the `Facebook` class, but as it was never imported in the Facebook.php file, I thought it did not matter at all.

Am I wrong (in that case please point to the relevant documentation), or is this a bug?

Comment: Likely need more code as i dont see an issue currently

Comment: In my case I made a mistake in namespaces ...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is a bug confirmed in PHP that may affect the behavior you see. It is supposed to fatal error, but with opcache enabled, it may still execute flawlessly.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66773

If it still concerns you, please vote for the bug.

Comment: Looks like this was indeed a bug, as opposed to what other answers say. The bug you mention and [#66862](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66862) have been fixed on 10 November 2016.

Comment: @dliche Probably because PHP was updated since the last restart.

Answer (score 30):

No, this is not a bug. As mentioned in [Using namespaces: Aliasing/Importing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

> use A\Library\Session;

is the same as:

```
use A\Library\Session as Session;
```

So try using something like:

```
use A\Library\Session as AnotherSessionClassName;
```

Comment: As I said to John Cartwright, it now works and I can't explain why. Looks like this goes against your answer; have you tried to reproduce it yourself? Any comment on this?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your case. So I created your directory structure ie A\Library and My\Application and the mentioned files, And I added some test code at the end of Facebook.php to create a session object. But I didn't understand how you used `use` clause to import Session class! I added a `require('../../A/Library/Session.php');` before `use` statement and it worked perfectly!

Comment: `use` just aliases the short name to the FQCN in the current file, while `require` executes the code contained in the target file, they're  totally different! What do you mean?

Comment: I know but you didn't mention in your question how you included _Session class_ file. I mean you didn't specified where exactly your `require` clause went. It's critical to this discussion! Maybe you have included both files, maybe you have not!

Comment: My classes are autoloaded, and yes, they've probably both been included at the time this code was executed.

Comment: There seems to be some problem with __autoload! I used spl_autoload_register and it worked perfectly! If you like I'll add my code as a seperate post.

Comment: I'm using the composer autoloader, I doubt the autoload mechanism makes any difference.

Comment: I don't what is composer. I'm talking about standard php language features. As mentioned in [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) there are two ways of autoloading: usind `__autoload()` and `spl_autoload_register()`. The `__autoload()` one is the discouraged way. I use php 5.5 and in this case the `__autoload()` one resulted in error. It seems the `__autoload()` does not handle namespaces correctly!

Comment: [composer](http://getcomposer.org/) is the *de facto* standard for dependency management in PHP, and comes with its autoloader based on `spl_autoload_register()`. But again, that should not matter. By the way, both `spl_autoload_register()` and `__autoload()` work with namespaces, the difference is that `spl_autoload_register()` allows multiple autoloaders to cohabit.

Comment: This is the code I used for facebook.php. I worked perfectly. Maybe it's useful for your examining. `<?php
namespace My\Application;

function my_autoloader($name) {
    var_dump($name);
 require('..\\..\\' . $name . '.php');
}

spl_autoload_register('\My\Application\my_autoloader');

use A\Library\Session;

class Facebook {
}

$a = new Session;`

Answer (score 13):

> The only problem I can see is that another Session class exists in the
>   same namespace as the Facebook class, but as it was never imported in
>   the Facebook.php file, I thought it did not matter at all.

Yes, it does matter. This is why you don't need to "import" classes from the same namespace. If you have conflicting names from different namespaces, you need to alias the class.

```
namespace My\Application;
use A\Library\Session as ASession; // choose a proper alias name here

class Facebook { ... }
```

Comment: I still don't understand why. To me, if I use Session from within `My\Application`, and there is no `use` for this one, then it would resolve it as `My\Application\Session`. But if there is one, it would use this one. The doc clearly says that imports are *per file*, so why would it look for classes defined in another file?

Comment: It's not the use statement that causes the issue. The problem is your \My\Application namespace has a \My\Application\Session class. Therefore, if you import another Session class into the scope of your \My\Application namespace (via use) you will have a conflicting Session class.

Comment: But because PHP is a dynamic language, that should not matter because the interpreter might not *know* at that time that there's a Session class in this namespace?

Comment: Weird, this now works with no explanation. Looks like I'm doing the same thing I was doing before! So it looks like PHP does allow this? I actually tried to reproduce my sample code above in isolation, and PHP does not complain.

Comment: yep, confirmed, it does work now. I can't reproduce the conditions that made it fail now. Have you tried it on your own? Any comment?

Answer (score 1):

I've read the thread about the issue, but I tested on many PHP versions (php 5.5, 5.6, 7.*, x32, x64, vc11, vc14, vc5). I'm using Laravel with Laragon. But, when I build up the server with `php artisan serve` (and open the server at http://localhost:8000) I have the problem of "the namespace that some Class was already used" and stuff.

I tested with and without opcache extension and nothing works, then I tested the virtual domain that Laragon provides and... voila, the error just disappeared and now I can work OK. I don't know what was happening, my namespaces were OK, I had an alias but the same code works in many machine without problem (AWS, local, prod, dev, etc) but only in my machine I had the problem just as I described it.

So, if someone is working with Laravel (5.1) and is having this issue, try the virtual host of Laragon.