# PHP States class is already in use

Tags: php

I have a simple php file with the following

```
<?php
     require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/assets/includes/inc.init.php');

     $username = $_GET['username'];
     $password = hash('sha256', $_GET['password']);

     echo $ecom->userManagement->doLogin($username, $password) == null;
```

this is suppose to print a simple number 0 or 1.

but for some reason it wants to tell me the ecom class is already in use

```
Fatal error: Cannot declare class Ecom, because the name is already in use in /var/www/html/core/class.ecom.php on line 19
```

here is the inc.init.php file

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");

//TODO: Check Session

$config = parse_ini_file('config.ini');

$mysqli = new mysqli($config['db_host'], $config['db_user'], $config['db_password'], $config['db_name']);

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/core/class.ecom.php');
$ecom = new Ecom($mysqli);

//TODO: Move the creation to when an item is added.
$cart = null;

if(isset($_COOKIE['cart_key'])) {
    $cart = $ecom->cartManagement->getCart($_COOKIE['cart_key']);

    if(!$cart->check()) {
        $cart->delete();
        $cart = $ecom->cartManagement->create($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        setcookie('cart_key', $cart->key, time()+60*60*24*365, '/', 'domain.com');
    }
} else {
    $cart = $ecom->cartManagement->create($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    setcookie('cart_key', $cart->key, time()+60*60*24*365, '/', 'domain.com');
}

$cart->updateExpiration();
?>
```

the ecom class is only ever called once and declared once.

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/core/class.ecom.php');
$ecom = new Ecom($mysqli);
```

i have a similar file that works just fine that looks like this

```
<?php
require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/assets/includes/inc.init.php');

$type = $_GET['type'];

if($type == "add") {
    $cart->addItem($_GET['id']);
}

else if($type == "remove") {
    $cart->removeItem($_GET['id']);
}

else if($type == "update") {
    $cart->updateItems();
}

echo 0;
```

Comment: have you tried changing `require` to `require_once`?

Comment: and the result was?

Comment: i bet its in "class.ecom.php" search it for new

Comment: If it was in class ecom why would the other pages work fine. Its just this page.

Comment: @cmorrissey the same

Comment: the error is clear, its already been declared, so find out where. sigh

Comment: Im not sure where because i have another file with almost the same exact lines that work perfectly

Comment: Possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746481/cannot-use-x-as-y-because-the-name-is-already-in-use-even-though-its-nothttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746481/cannot-use-x-as-y-because-the-name-is-already-in-use-even-though-its-not

Comment: Try: class_exists('your_class_name') || require('you class path');